# Binding to properties of a control in a tooltip

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I want to display some properties of a (custom) Label in its Tooltip,
but I can't seem to get it working correctly so must be doing something wrong:

```
<Label.ToolTip>
    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5" Padding="5">
       <Label Content="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Label}}}"/>  
    </Border>
</Label.ToolTip>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the output in Visual Studio give any indication of what's going wrong?

Comment: Yeah it could not find the instance of Label I was looking for. 
But as you can see I already found the solution :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution

```
<ToolTip  DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
```

Thnx to Karl!

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2007/12/29/wpf-sample-series-data-binding-in-tooltip/